# How to create a list by repetitive multiplication?

Tags: python, list

I need to do below exercise. Yet I am having problems as creating a list like mentioned below.

Create a list with sales considering the following assumptions:

> inicial valueSales =1000 growth rate = 10% number of years = 6

Result should be like that:

```
[1000, 1100.0, 1210.0, 1331.0, 1464.1000000000001, 1610.5100000000002]
```

Like closest answer of mine is like below, if anyone can guide from here or from another starting point Id be glad:

```
yearly_growths = [1000]

yearly_growths.extend(i * 1.1 for i in range(5))

print(yearly_growths)
```

Answer (score 1):

#primitive answer

```
initial_price=100
rate=0.1
year=6 

my_list=[initial_price]

for i in range(year-1):

    my_list.append(my_list[-1]*(1+rate))

print(my_list)
```

#more mathematical

```
initial_price=100
rate=0.1
year=6

print([initial_price*(1+rate)**i for i in range(year)])
```

Comment: Neither produces the correct result.

Comment: Thanks, it was quite helpful.

Comment: @KellyBundy Both do. Have you checked?

Comment: @DYZ This is so obvious that I don't need to. Did you?

Comment: @KellyBundy You must be kidding. Both answers are correct (if properly scaled).

Comment: @DYZ They have wrong values and the wrong number of values.

Comment: @KellyBundy Whatever :) Suit yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Does this help?

```
initial=1000
rate=0.1
years=6

a=[initial]

for i in range(years-1):
    x=a[i]*(1+rate)
    a.append(x)
    
print (a)
```